# Return "blank" entity if entity does not exist using QueryBuilder

Tags: android, greendao

I would like to be able to return a "DefaultEntity" if the query created by QueryBuilder does not exist, example :

```
myDao.queryBuilder().where(MyEntityDao.Properties.Id.eq(100)).unique()
```

If there is no entity with such ID (in this case `100`), I don't want to generate an exception, but rather return an Entity that contains some default information.

The use case here is that we have a mobile application that has data stored in the local database that could not be up-to-date compared to data contained in a server, so when I want to display an information from a relation of an Entity, this could lead to a crash when calling `toString()` afterwards.

I checked the documentation and all over StackOverflow and found these options, but none suits my use case for the following reasons :

- Surrounding with `try/catch` blocks : There is A LOT of lines where I would need to do that, I wanted something generic
- Creating a default entity : This doesn't really resolve the problem as I would need to `try/catch` anyway
- Using `uniqueOrThrow()` : This would generate a `DaoException`, but then I wasn't able to return something by default, I can just catch that kind of Exception in a custom ExceptionHandler but nothing else

An example of solution would be to override calls to `unique()` for example, so I could `try/catch` in a single place of the code and return an Entity following the type I am querying.

Any ideas ?